# How do you maintain a simple credit debit statement using python

Tags: python, oop

I am using the following codes in python(oops) so to maintain credit debit statement.The Classdef_Cash.py file has the main structure of the program and Cash_001.py file has the credit and debit codes.Everything is working fine,except the credit and debit values are not being updated regularly.Could anyone help me in this ? Please refer both the files and run Cash_001.py file."""

`Classdef_Cash_001.py` is the first file and `Cash_001.py` is second file

```
class Cash:

       def __init__(self, DATE, VOUCHER, SPECIFICATION, INITIAL_AMOUNT, CREDIT,DEBIT, REMARKS, BALANCE):
            self.DATE = DATE
            self.VOUCHER = VOUCHER
            self.SPECIFICATION = SPECIFICATION
            self.CREDIT = CREDIT
            self.DEBIT = DEBIT
            self.REMARKS = REMARKS
            self.BALANCE = INITIAL_AMOUNT

       def Spending(self,DATE,VOUCHER,SPECIFICATION,DEBIT,REMARKS):
            self.DATE = DATE
            self.VOUCHER = VOUCHER
            self.SPECIFICATION = SPECIFICATION
            self.REMARKS = REMARKS
            self.BALANCE -= DEBIT

       def CashInflow(self,DATE,VOUCHER,SPECIFICATION,CREDIT,REMARKS):
            self.DATE = DATE
            self.VOUCHER = VOUCHER
            self.SPECIFICATION = SPECIFICATION
            self.REMARKS = REMARKS
            self.BALANCE += CREDIT

       def dump(self):
            s = 'DATE: %s, VOUCHER: %s, SPECIFICATION: %s , CREDIT: %s ,DEBIT: %s ,REMARKS :%s ,BALANCE :%s ' % \
                (self.DATE,self.VOUCHER, self.SPECIFICATION, self.CREDIT, self.DEBIT, self.REMARKS,self.BALANCE)
            print s
```

`Cash_001.py` is the second file

```
from Classdef_Cash_001 import Cash

p1=Cash('01/10/2018','000','CARRY FORWARD',2000,0,0,'REMAINDER','0')
p1.dump()
p1.Spending('01/10/2018','001','OIL',200,'JOHN')
p1.dump()
p1.CashInflow('02/10/2018','002','SALES',10000,'REF179800')
p1.dump()
p1.Spending('03/10/2018','003','GAS',200,'GEORGE')
p1.dump()
p1.CashInflow('03/10/2018','004','SALES',50000,'REF179801')
p1.dump()
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what results you get and what results you expect ?

Comment: Unrelated, but your design seems quite wrong to me - you are overwriting the instance attributes, when very probably want to keep track of all operations. You really want two distinct classes: one representing discrete operations (should be immutable), and one keeping track of those operations.

Comment: Please edit your post with __all__ relevant informations - what you get, __AND__ what you expect.

Comment: The credit and debit values cannot be zero at the same time .Either credit should be non zero or debit should be non zero for the cash that is spent or the cash that enters the account.The output is below.                                                                                                 DATE: 01/10/2018, VOUCHER: 000, SPECIFICATION: CARRY FORWARD , CREDIT: 0 ,DEBIT: 0 ,REMARKS :REMAINDER ,BALANCE :2000
DATE: 01/10/2018, VOUCHER: 001, SPECIFICATION: OIL , CREDIT: 0 ,DEBIT: 0 ,REMARKS :JOHN ,BALANCE :1800

Comment: Observed:DATE: 01/10/2018, VOUCHER: 001, SPECIFICATION: OIL , CREDIT: 0 ,DEBIT: 0 ,REMARKS :JOHN ,BALANCE :1800                                                                                      Expected:DATE: 01/10/2018, VOUCHER: 001, SPECIFICATION: OIL , CREDIT: 0 ,DEBIT: 200 ,REMARKS :JOHN ,BALANCE :1800

Comment: Plaese refer my comment above.please view the observed and expected results.The debit value should be 200 but in the output window it showing zero.

Comment: PLEASE EDIT YOUR POST - no one is going to try and guess where a newline should start in your comments.

Comment: is there any provision to attach the screen shot?

Comment: Don't post images. Copy paste the TEXT version, properly formatted (newlines at the right place etc). text can be copy-pasted and is garanteed to stay part of the question. Images cannot be copy pasted, and may disappear, making the whole question useless for future references (remember that SO is meant to be a knowledge base, not a developers forum).

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers: I just now found out the answer.Thank you.

Comment: If you "found the anwser" then please post it as an answer - else you wasted everyone's time (and specially mine) without contributing anything to the community.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers: I arrived at the solution after hours of tryout.With your permission can I upload the codes so that you could get the clear picture regarding the requirement.

Comment: Why do you ask for permission ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below codes.This is exactly what I was looking for a unified credit debit balance statement.Whenever there is inflow of money, the debit is forced to be zero and whenever there is an expenditure,the credit is forced to be zero.Both credit and debit remain zero only in the first line of the output which is carry forward from the previous month.This is similar to the concept whenever there is an input,the output is disabled and whenever there is output, the input is disabled.Please run Cash_001.py file.

```
   #Classdef_Cash_001.py 
   class Cash:

   def __init__(self, DATE, VOUCHER, SPECIFICATION, INITIAL_AMOUNT, CREDIT,DEBIT,
   REMARKS, BALANCE):
        self.DATE = DATE
        self.VOUCHER = VOUCHER
        self.SPECIFICATION = SPECIFICATION
        self.CREDIT = CREDIT
        self.DEBIT = DEBIT
        self.REMARKS = REMARKS
        self.BALANCE = INITIAL_AMOUNT

   def Spending(self,DATE,VOUCHER,SPECIFICATION,DEBIT,CREDIT,REMARKS):
        self.DATE = DATE
        self.VOUCHER = VOUCHER
        self.SPECIFICATION = SPECIFICATION
        self.REMARKS = REMARKS
        self.DEBIT = DEBIT
        self.CREDIT = 0
        self.BALANCE -= DEBIT

   def CashInflow(self,DATE,VOUCHER,SPECIFICATION,CREDIT,DEBIT,REMARKS):
        self.DATE = DATE
        self.VOUCHER = VOUCHER
        self.SPECIFICATION = SPECIFICATION
        self.REMARKS = REMARKS
        self.CREDIT = CREDIT
        self.DEBIT = 0
        self.BALANCE += CREDIT

   def dump(self):
        s = 'DATE: %s, VOUCHER: %s, SPECIFICATION: %s , CREDIT: %s ,DEBIT: %s 
            ,REMARKS :%s ,BALANCE :%s ' % \
            (self.DATE,self.VOUCHER, self.SPECIFICATION, self.CREDIT, self.DEBIT,
            self.REMARKS, self.BALANCE)
        print s

  #Cash_001.py
  from Classdef_Cash_001 import Cash

  p1=Cash('01/10/2018','000','CARRY FORWARD',2000,0,0,'REMAINDER',0)
  p1.dump()
  p1.Spending('01/10/2018','001','OIL',200,0,'JOHN')
  p1.dump()
  p1.CashInflow('02/10/2018','002','SALES',1000,0,'REF179800')
  p1.dump()
  p1.Spending('03/10/2018','003','GAS',200,0,'GEORGE')
  p1.dump()
  p1.CashInflow('03/10/2018','004','SALES',5000,0,'REF179801')
  p1.dump()
```